# Hive partition table entry

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am creating a process A that inserts records into hive partitioned table on daily basis. As soon as the table insert is complete I want to trigger another process B.Process B is present in another server.
I am planning to check the partition entry for the current day to see if hive insert process is complete or not from Server B. 
In hive , is the partition entry is made just before query execution or after the query process is complete.

Consider table t has partition 'date'.

> show partitions t

date=2018-01-01

date=2018-01-02

When a hive.hql is triggered for date=2018-01-03 , and in execution when "show partition" is given , will it give new partition entry or only after completion of the process the new partition entry will come?

Comment: New partition key/values are created only when there is data for the respective partitions.

Comment: Agree. But at what point the partition entry will reflect in metastore. After the complete insert process is complete or before that?

Comment: I think depending or partition exist to make sure Data Loading is completed it not a good solution, Better would be to wrap the sql to load data into script and create a trigger file at the end process.

Comment: After the write process is committed (flushed) to HDFS